# Using rasterFromXYZ in R for QGIS under Krige-Baye

Tags: r, interpolation, qgis-modeler

I am trying to run the script below in R for QGIS to produce a raster result.

Everything runs fine but the image is not produced since the command rasterFromXYZ encounters a mismatch of elements in the prediction locations and the predicted values.

How can I get the correct results?

```
    >MySript=group  
    >rainfall= vector  
    >output=output raster  
    >require(sp)  
    >require(geoR)  
    >require(raster)  
    >locss=pred_grid(c(35.06,35.7), c(-1.63,-1.0), by = 0.02)  
    >data1=as.geodata(rainfall)  
    >MC <- model.control(trend.d = "1st", trend.l = "1st", cov.model="matern",kappa = 1.5)  
    >PC <- prior.control(phi.discrete = seq(0, 0.05, l = 40),phi.prior = "reciprocal", tausq.rel.prior = "unif",tausq.rel.discrete = seq(0, 0.005, l = 20))  
    >OC <- output.control(n.post = length(locss[,1]), moments = T)
    >set.seed(268)  
    >skb <- krige.bayes(data1, loc = locss,model = MC,prior = PC,output = OC)  
    >output = rasterFromXYZ(cbind(locss, skb$predict))  
    >image(output)
```

**Results**

```
>  output = rasterFromXYZ(cbind(locss, skb$predict))  
>         Warning message:
>         In matrix(as.numeric(xyz), ncol = ncol(xyz), nrow = nrow(xyz)) :
>         NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Do you understand what this is doing? Have you read the documentation for the output of `krige.bayes`? Taking the same number of samples from the posterior distribution as points in your data (n.post=...) seems an odd thing to do - why? What aspect of the posterior distribution do you want to map? You can get it from the `skb$predictive` component of the returned object.

Comment: I have 140 data locations with rainfall data. I have 1056 prediction locations (locss). The reason i take n.post=no of prediction location (not data points) is to enable me have equal number of row for the prediction location and the predicted value. Attempts to have n.post>no of prediction location returns the error below when i try to cbind them.                                        Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1056, 1, 3000 . I there a better way to cbind when the number of rows differ?

Comment: n.post is the number of samples from the posterior distribution at each prediction point. With standard kriging you get a mean and a variance which define a normal distribution at each point. With Bayesian kriging you get n.post samples from the posterior distribution at each point. n.post has got nothing to do with the number of *locations* you are predicting at. You want n.post to be as large as possible (within the time you have to do the analysis) to get a better measure of the shape of the posterior distribution.

Comment: thank you very much. I have extracted the mean of the predictive sample using r =sbk$predictive$mean and used output = rasterFromXYZ(cbind(locss, r)) to get he required predictive map in QGIS. Same for prediction variance. Thank you